# Phonegap: Getting Started with Android? -- on Linux

Tags: android, linux, cordova, ubuntu-12.04

On Phonegap.com, the [Getting Started with Android? page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) have the sections:

- 3A. Setup your PATH environment variable on **Mac OS**
- 3B. Setup your PATH environment variable on **Windows**

but **no section for Linux. Why ? what should I do if on Linux (Ubuntu) ?**

Comment: http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2013/05/How-to-Use-PhoneGap-on-Linux-Ubuntu-or-Android-Application-Development.html check this . Is it helpful for you ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I myself use phonegap on linux, for that i have installed android SDK via Eclipse (Eclipse JUNO for linux) and for ease of access, I use applaud plugin for eclipse.

Steps for installation:

1. Download eclipse from "Software center" or from eclipse's website.
2. For Android SDK use instructions given on Android developers' site (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html )
3. Applaud plugin(Optional): http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start This site contains a step-by-step procedure of installing Android SDK and applaud plugin.

PATH ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE

On Linux, the PATH environment variable can be defined in your ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile file. If you have either of those files, use a text editor such as gedit, vi, or Emacs to open the file and look for a line that exports the PATH variable. If you find such a line, edit it to add the full path of the tools directory to the path. If there is no such line, you can add a line like this:

export PATH=${PATH}:your_sdk_dir/tools
where you put the full path in place of

your_sdk_dir.

For further help, please refer to

http://fyi.oreilly.com/2009/02/setting-up-your-android-develo.html

Comment: May you go slower for a new users like me and use numbered list for steps. Secondly, what about the Path environment variable ?

Comment: Generally speaking, put a clear hierarchy/structure in your answer, with bullets or lists, that help make process clearer. Your answer have been happily accepted!